# Как сделать очередь задач под Linux?

Tags: php, bash

Есть веб-фронтенд (nginx, php-fpm), принимающий файлы от посетителей. И есть долгоиграющая задача перекодирования этих файлов (ffmpeg, shell), не требующая их участия.

Как проще организовать очередь задач в рамках одного сервера?

Два бита состояний: **очередь** (пуста | есть задачи), и **worker** (idle | busy).

Хочется избежать поллинга, чтобы энкодер запускался сразу же, как появляется задача, или есть следующая. Т.е. какое-то типа, realtime, event-driven решение.

Смотрел на [RabbitMQ](http://www.rabbitmq.com/), но не смог скомпилировать [CLI примочки](https://github.com/rmt/amqptools) для него. Пробовал поставить [Torque](http://www.clusterresources.com/torquedocs21/1.1installation.shtml), но тоже возникла <strike>жо</strike> непредвиденная сложность с установкой:

```
/usr/sbin/pbs_server: undefined symbol: disr_commit
```

Есть ли что-то надежное и простое как дрова? =)

Answer (score 2):

Пока остановился на [Redis](http://redis.io/), с его [list'ами](http://redis.io/topics/data-types) и [BLPOP](http://redis.io/commands/blpop). Написал shell скрипт, который ловит поступающие задачи, ставит флаги и выполняет.

Answer (score 1):

очень неплохо под это подходит inotify - просто выполняйте по очереди все  такски описанные файлами в директории, и ожидайте новых тасок с пом-ю inotify :) можно еще на perl + Parallel::ForkManage сделать выполнение задач параллельным, организовать общение с мастер-процессом и другие вкусности.